# Is there itemController for new each syntax in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

The new syntax

{{#each pages as |page| itemController="listedPage"}}

causes parse error. Is item Controller usable with the new "each" syntax?
If yes, how to specify it? If not, what is the preferred way to use computed properties with the items of "each"?

Answer (score 3):

Controllers are being phased out - so I would recommend using components..

### Component for Each Item

You could implement a 'listed-page' component which would look something like this:

Your template:

```
<ul>
{{#each pages as |page|}}
    {{listed-page page=page}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

The component:

```
## components/listed-page.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  page: null,

  pageNumberFancy: function() {
    return '^'+this.get('page.number')+'^';
  }.property('page.number')
})

## templates/components/listed-page.hbs

Number: {{page.number}} ({{pageNumberFancy}})
```

The output:

```
<div class='template-level'>
  <ul class='template-level'>
    <li class='listed-page-level'>Number: 1 (^1^)</li>
    <li class='listed-page-level'>Number: 2 (^2^)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Component for the List

Or a listed-pages component - if 'pages' is an array computed property - or both:

Your template:

```
{{listed-pages pages=pages}}
```

The component:

```
## components/listed-pages.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',

  pages: null,

  pagesPlusOne: function() {
    var pagesList = this.get('pages');
    pagesList.addObject(specialPage);
    return pagesList;
  }.property('pages.[]')
})

## templates/components/listed-pages.hbs

{{#each pagesPlusOne as |page|}}
  {{listed-page page=page}}
{{/each}}
```

The output:

```
<div class='template-level'>
  <ul class='listed-pages-level'>
    <li class='listed-page-level'>Number: 1 (^1^)</li>
    <li class='listed-page-level'>Number: 2 (^2^)</li>
    <li class='listed-page-level'>Number: +1 (^+1^)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. There is no reason to want itemController any more.